# Search DOM nodes and return the parent if any descendants contain a match

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, dom

Let's say I have the following:

```
<div className="container">

  <div id="one" class="item">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <span>foo</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="two" class="item">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div>foo</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="three" class="item">
    <span>foo</span>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="four" class="item">
    <span></span>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>foo</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I want to return all items that contain a span with text content "foo" anywhere within them. In the above example I would expect 1, 2, and 4 to be returned.

I've written a recursive method but am stumbling somewhere, I think in how I'm handling the return. This currently returns all items.

```
const hasFoo = (el) => {
  const isSpan = el.tagName?.toLowerCase() === "span";
  const isMatch = el.innerText?.toLowerCase() === "foo";

  if (isSpan && isMatch) {
    return true;
  } else if (el.children?.length) {
    const nodes = [...el.children];
    return nodes.forEach(node => hasFoo(node));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
const nodes = [...container.children];
const filtered = nodes.filter(node => hasFoo(node));
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues.

className is not a valid alternate for the class attribute. Because of that, `document.getElementsByClassName("container")` returns an empty array.

`return nodes.forEach(node => hasFoo(node))` will ALWAYS return `undefined`.
According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> forEach() executes the callbackFn function once for each array
> element; unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value
> undefined and is not chainable.

Use a for loop instead

```
const hasFoo = (el) => {
  const isSpan = el.tagName?.toLowerCase() === "span";
  const isMatch = el.innerText?.toLowerCase() === "foo";
  if (isSpan && isMatch) {
    return true;
  }
  const nodes = [...el.children];
  for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (hasFoo(nodes[i]))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! And className was a pasting typo, my React is showing.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the problems with `className` and your `forEach`.  But for better experience that an explicit loop, use `Array.prototype.some`, like this:

```js
const hasFoo = (el) => 
  (el .tagName ?.toLowerCase() === "span" && el .textContent ?.toLowerCase() === "foo") ||
  [...el .children ?? []] .some (hasFoo)

const foos = [... document .querySelectorAll (".container > *")] .filter (hasFoo)

foos .forEach (div => div .classList .add ('hasFoo'))
```

```css
div {border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: .125em; padding: .125em;}
span {border: 1px solid #000; padding: .125em;}
div.hasFoo {background-color: yellow; border: 2px dotted #00f;}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div id="one" class="item"><div></div><div></div><div><span>foo</span></div></div><div id="two" class="item"><div></div><div></div><div><div>foo</div></div></div><div id="three" class="item"><span>foo</span><div></div><div><span></span></div></div><div id="four" class="item"><span></span><div></div><div><div><span>foo</span></div></div></div></div>
```

Here we mark all `<div>`s with a light border, all `<span>`s with a darker one and highlight all the children of `.container` which have a `foo`-span with a yellow background and a dotted border.

Comment: This is a great approach, thank you! On a side note, I'd be very curious to hear more about your spacing conventions.

Comment: @Ben: This spacing convention is just something I picked up from another user here on SO, who has since stopped doing so.  I simply find it more readable and like focusing on property/method access as equal in importance to direct variable referencing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recursive, but I prefer to return a filtered array of `items` based on the condition/requirement.

```js
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item'));
const itemsWithFooSpans = items.filter(item => {
    let hasFoo = false;
    const spans = item.querySelectorAll('span');
    spans.forEach(span => {
        console.log('span: ', span);
        if (span && span.textContent && span.textContent === 'foo') {
            hasFoo = true;
        }
    });
    return hasFoo;
});
```

Comment: Instead of your `spans.forEach` + `return hasFoo` you'd be better doing directly `return spans.some(span => span?.textContent === "foo");`

Answer (score 0):

You can first target all the spans that are inside your container with a simple `container.querySelectorAll("span")` and then filter in only the ones with the proper text content.
Once you have this list you only have to retrieve each of these spans ancestor matching the `.item` selector. This can be achieved with the [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method.
In case you may have multiple such spans per item, you may want to deduplicate the resulting Array:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const spans = [...container.querySelectorAll("span")]
  .filter(el => el.textContent.toLowerCase() === "foo");
const items = Array.from(new Set( // avoid duplicates
  spans.map(el => el.closest(".item"))
)).filter(Boolean); // avoid null

console.log(items.map(el => el.id));
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="one" class="item">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <span>foo</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="two" class="item">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div>foo</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="three" class="item">
    <span>foo</span>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="four" class="item">
    <span></span>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>foo</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".container");
var spans = elem.querySelectorAll("span");
var found = [];
spans.forEach(item => {
  if (/foo/i.test(item.textContent || "")) {
    found.push({
      span: item,
      parent: item.closest("div.item")
    });
  }
})
console.log("found", found)
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="one" class="item">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <span>foo</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="two" class="item">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div>foo</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="three" class="item">
    <span>foo</span>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="four" class="item">
    <span></span>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>foo</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```